# Make navigation bar active

Tags: navigation, navbar, highlight

I'm trying to make the navigation bar active (highlight for example) on the page we're on.
For example, if we're in the home page, it will highlight the home button. I'm trying to make it so when we are in the News page for example, it highlights the news button on the navbar

Here's my html code:

```
    <nav>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
        <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="hamburger" id="hamburger">
                    <div>
                        <span class="line-1"></span>
                        <span class="line-2"></span>
                        <span class="line-3"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        

            </div>
        </label>
        <script src="nav.js"></script>
        <label class="logo"><a href="index.html">JR-Koders</a></label>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="text active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="nav.html" class="text" id="my-news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#j-koder" class="text">J-Koder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#r-koder" class="text">R-Koder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Koders" class="text">Koders</a></li>
            <li><a href="#search" id="my-search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial;
}

/* navigation bar */
nav{
    background: black;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}


.fa-search{
    color: white;
}

label.logo{
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 80px;
    padding: 0 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* n'affecte que le "logo" */
a { color: inherit; }



/* each element at the right of the nav bar */
nav ul li a{
    /* color: white; */
    font-size: 17px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 7px 13px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #20C20E;
}

/* n'affecte que les éléments de droite de la nav bar,
.active is the class of the element the user is currently on */
nav ul li a.active, nav ul li a:hover{
    background: #20C20E;
    color: black;
    transition: 1.5s;
}




.checkbtn{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

#check{
    display: none;
}

/* SMALL SMARTPHONE BEGINNING */
/* If screen is smaller than a normal cellphone, Then make the logo smaller */
@media (max-width: 870px){
    label.logo{
        font-size: 30px;
        padding-left: 25px;
        color: white;
    }
    nav ul li a{
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
/* SMALL SMARTPHONE END */


/* NORMAL SMARTPHONE BEGINNING */
@media (max-width: 981px) {
    .checkbtn{
        display: block;
        margin-top: 4.7vh;
        margin-right: 7vh;
    }
    ul{
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: #2c3e50;
        top: 80px;
        left: -100%;
        text-align: center;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    nav ul li{
        display: block;
        margin: 50px 0;
        line-height: 30px;
    }
    nav ul li a{
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    a:hover,a.active{
        background: none;
        color: #20C20E;
        background-color: black;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    #check:checked ~ ul{
        left: 0;
    }
    label.logo {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    label.a:hover {
        background: white;
        transition: 3s;
    }

    /* hamburger BEGINNING */
    .container {
        width: 0px;
        height: 100vh;
        background: black;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .hamburger, .menu2{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-top: -735px;
        margin-right: -15px;
        background-color: #20C20E;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;

    }

    .hamburger div, .menu2 div{
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        margin: 10px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .hamburger span, .menu2 span{
        background: #fff;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2.5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        transition: transform 0.4s, width 0.5s;
    }

    /* espace les lignes pour qu'elles ne soient pas les unes sur les autres */
    .hamburger .line-1 {
        transform: translate(-50%,-12.5px);
    }

    .hamburger .line-3{
        transform: translate(-50%,10px);
    }

    /* quand le hamburger est en mode croix */
    .openhamburger .line-1{
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    }

    .openhamburger .line-3{
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(45deg);
    }

    .openhamburger .line-2{
        width: 0;
    }
    /* hamburger END */
}
```